# vue-select : Passing option slot from grandparent component in VueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-select

I am using custom dropdown component 'vue-select', it has a slot option through which we can customize the options view as shown in this document -> https://vue-select.org/guide/slots.html

Similar thing I want to achieve it by passing a slot from grandparent component.
Here is what I have tried.

App.vue(Grandparent component)

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-select-wrapper v-model="selectedData" :options-data="[{
        id:1,
        label: 'New York'
      }, {
        id:2,
        label : 'London'
      }]">
      <template v-slot:option-data="option">
        {{option.id}} -
        {{ option.label }}
      </template>
    </v-select-wrapper>
  </div>
</template>
```

VSelectWrapper.vue(Parent component)

```
<template>
  <v-select :options="optionsData" :value="value" @input="inputChanged">

    <template v-slot:option="option">
      <slot name="option-data"/>
    </template>
  </v-select>
</template>

<script>
  import vSelect from "vue-select";

  export default {
    name: "VSelectWrapper",
    components: {
      vSelect
    },
    props: {
      optionsData: {type: Array},
      value: {}
    },
    methods: {
      inputChanged(val) {
        this.$emit("input", val);
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

The output I receive is only '-'(hyphen) character in dropdown option. The data is not getting passed through the slot.

How can it be achieved?

Comment: Probably not the solution, but you need to specify a constructor (for this `value` prop) rather than an empty object.

Comment: @YomS. Agreed, but `value` doesn't seem to be passed down as a prop in the first place. In @aniket_777 s Grandparent component.

Comment: @Paul Bovis, the reason I kept `value` as a prop is to make `v-model` for my Vue-wrapper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your slot props are not passed down is because you did not bind anything on the slot to pick up from by the children. To do so, you simply need to add `v-bind="option"` where `option` is the slot property of the `vue-select` component itself:

#### `VSelectWrapper.vue`

```html
<v-select
  :options="optionsData"
  :value="value"
  @input="inputChanged">
  <template v-slot:option="option">
    <slot name="option-data" v-bind="option"></slot>
  </template>
</v-select>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much :)